# how to trim dpkg upgraded packages list

Tags: grep, awk

Latest upgrade borked my system and I`m trying to revert the last upgrade. I opened my comp with live USB and chrooted to partition that is OS installed. I get the upgraded packages with

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep upgrade >>upgradeddpkg
```

It lists pakages like

```
2014-03-14 15:31:45 upgrade libprocps0:i386 1:3.3.3-2ubuntu5.3 1:3.3.3-3
2014-03-14 15:31:52 upgrade libreadline-dev:i386 6.2-9ubuntu1 6.2+dfsg-0.1
2014-03-14 15:31:53 upgrade libreadline6-dev:i386 6.2-9ubuntu1 6.2+dfsg-0.1
2014-03-14 15:31:55 upgrade readline-common:all 6.2-9ubuntu1 6.2+dfsg-0.1
2014-03-14 15:32:25 upgrade libreadline6:i386 6.2-9ubuntu1 6.2+dfsg-0.1
2014-03-14 15:32:33 upgrade libudev0:i386 175-0ubuntu19 175-7.2
2014-03-14 15:32:40 upgrade libdevmapper-dev:i386 2:1.02.74-6ubuntu4 2:1.02.74-8
2014-03-14 15:32:42 upgrade libdevmapper-event1.02.1:i386 2:1.02.74-6ubuntu4 2:1.02.74-8
2014-03-14 15:32:43 upgrade libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 2:1.02.74-6ubuntu4 2:1.02.74-8
2014-03-14 15:32:44 upgrade dmsetup:i386 2:1.02.74-6ubuntu4 2:1.02.74-8
```

How can I get only the name of the packages by means of grep, awk or whatever tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below command,

```
awk ' { print $4 } ' upgradeddpkg > upgrade.txt
```

If you don't want the colon `:` then run,

```
awk -F ':' ' { print $1 } ' upgrade.txt > upgrade1.txt
```

#### Explanation:

```
awk ' { print $4 } ' upgradeddpkg > upgrade.txt
```

In this, awk takes the input from  `upgradeddpkg` and prints only the $4(column number 4).That output was redirected to `upgrade.txt` file.So upgrade.txt file contains only the package names with colon.To remove the colon and its upcoming part(following), you have to run the second command.By default awk considers space as a delimiter.

```
awk -F ':' ' { print $1 } ' upgrade.txt > upgrade1.txt
```

Delimiter colon was manually set and awk considers colon as a delimiter instead of space.Now awk takes the input(stdin) from the upgrade.txt and prints(stdout) the coloumn1(part before the colon).Finally the standard output was redirected to `upgrade1.txt`.Now it contains only the package names.

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @AdityaPatil sure, plz wait.

Comment: almost done but it includes colons too like `libgtk-3-dev:i386
base-files:i386
bash:i386
dpkg:i386
e2fslibs:i386
e2fsprogs:i386`

Comment: now run the second command, colon will be removed.Final package list will be appears on the upgrade1.txt.

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem using grep for the initial search in that it's including things like `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all`. I would use a single `awk` to match and pick the right field.

```
awk '$3=="upgrade" { print $4 }' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

By default awk splits each line based on spaces. The third field is the action (so we check that it equals "upgrade") and the fourth is the package name.

Some packages get upgraded a lot so you can cut out the noise of duplicates with:

```
awk '$3=="upgrade" { print $4 }' /var/log/dpkg.log | sort -u
```

---

I've seen Avinash's answer now... I'd be slightly cautious of snipping off the architectures... Depending on what you're doing, they could be as relevant as the package name... But if you did want to snip them out, I'd probably do that in the same `awk` statement:

```
awk '$3=="upgrade" { split($4, a, ":"); print a[1] }' /var/log/dpkg.log | sort -u
```

Alternatively, you could set multiple fields separators for `awk`, so that it splits *either* on spaces or on colons:

```
awk -F'[ :]' '$5=="upgrade" { print $6 }' /var/log/dpkg.log
```